# cakephp 3 form validation notEmpty

Tags: php, cakephp

I set the title field to be required.

```
$validator
->requirePresence('title', 'create')
->notEmpty('title');
```

the problem is that the title input is not marked as required.
I don't have this problem with another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after an hour. it was a little mistake.

in controller action I wrote:

```
$this->set('gallery');
```

while I should do this:

```
$this->set('gallery',$gallery);
```

sorry for wasting your time.